Trouble checking system integrety with Aide "aide.wrapper: command not found"
I used the instructions found in website https://webhostinggeeks.com/howto/how-to-check-system-integrity-on-ubuntu/ and followed them successfully to a point.

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install aide
sudo aideinit

Then the next step (5.) failed

sudo aide.wrapper --check

Output is as follows;
.......@...........:~$ sudo aide.wrapper --check
sudo: password for pop-pop:
sudo: aide.wrapper: command not found
I trying to learn Linux - can anyone help with this?

What is your Ubuntu version? On 24.04, apt changelog aide mentions "remove no longer needed aide.wrapper" in the release notes for version 0.16.2-87-g9804cf4-1 - so it looks like the guide you are following may not be up to date with the current usage

I am on 24.04 LTS.  I see this is listed as unstable.  Any suggestions on a better way to check on system integrity?

AFAIK "unstable" just refers to the upstream Debian release, it doesn't mean the software itself is "unstable". You likely just need to replace the removed aide.wrapper --check command with the new simpler aide --check (or plain aide, since --check appears to be the default action).
